# Debugging with url after site deployment to pythonanywhere server

Tags: python

The application is designed to upload files to the server with the ability to delete, download and view. After deploying the application to pythonanywhere, an error began to occur when I tried to view the contents of the file. Although the application and all the functions on my local machine worked fine. (If necessary, I can throw off all the code)

[image: Screenshot of error]

Answer (score 0):

You are not serving the static files that your app is creating. The help pages on PythonAnywhere cover how to set those up.